# Will Monero CPU mining always be feasible?

Tags: cpu-mining

Bitcoin mining, as far as I'm aware, hit a point where it can't be mined merely with a CPU, if you expect results.

Will Monero's mining remain constant (is "constant" even an appropriate term)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The algrithim Monero uses, CryptoNote, has a POW mechanism that makes it hard for asic miners to be developed, so that CPU mining and GPU mining will remain the standard. But the difficulty of mining coins will not be constant.

"The proof of work mechanism acts as a voting system. Thus, it is crucial that during the voting process all the participants have equal voting privileges. CryptoNote brings this equality with its egalitarian proof of work, utilizing built-in CPU instructions, which are very hard and too expensive to implement in special purpose devices, but perfectly suitable for ordinary PCs." [CryptoNote](https://cryptonote.org/inside#equal-proof-of-work)

Comment: The ASIC Miners were my fear; thank you for clearing that up a bit. I will read more on CryptoNote and the voting process.